# Increasing number of conditions within a loop R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I am currently experiencing somme difficulties in a R script, since the conditions required increase within the loop. Here's the explanation and an example.

1. Imagine a 10x10 matrix with 1 or 0 (either LISTE or Meldungen)

   `[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
    [1,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0     1
    [2,]    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     1
    [3,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1     0
    [4,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
    [5,]    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    1     0
    [6,]    0    1    1    1    0    1    1    1    0     1
    [7,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0     0
    [8,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    1    1     0
    [9,]    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     0
   [10,]    1    1    1    0    1    0    1    0    1     0`

   I would like a loop that loads this database at every iteration. And check the foloowing possibilities for every row and colum(i row and j column)

*1st iteration*
1. starting at j=1 to number of column
 if i,1=1 and i+1,1=0 then i+2,1=0

*2 iteration* (with original database)
starting at j=1 to number of column
if i,1=1 and i+1,1=0 and i+2,1=0 then i+3,1=0

*3 iteration* (with original database)
if i,1=1 and i+1,1=0 and i+2,1=0 and i+3,1=0 then i+4,1=0

and so on

I tried to following code

```
for(p in 2:time){
  LISTE_neu <- LISTE        #load original database      

  if(p == 2){
    for(i in 1:row_number){
      for(j in (1+p):column_number)){
        if(LISTE_neu[i,(j-p)]==1 & Meldungen_num[i,j-(p-1)]==0){LISTE_neu[i,j] <- 0}
      }
    }
    LISTE_neu_2 <- LISTE_neu
  }

  if(p == 3){
    for(i in 1:row_number){
      for(j in (1+p):column_number){
        if(LISTE_neu[i,(j-p)]==1 & Meldungen_num[i,j-(p-1)]==0 & Meldungen_num[i,(j-(p-2))]==0){LISTE_neu[i,j] <- 0}
      }
    }
    LISTE_neu_3 <- LISTE_neu
  }
}
```

However at this point it's working. However it's very painful to type this increasing conditions.

Do you have an idea how to make things simpler? le tme know if it's unclear

Comment: Please explain your actual goal in words and provide example input and expected output. Nested `for` loops is not how we do such things in R.

Comment: Sure. In this case, I have to update the code written by someone else. However the goal is that at each iteration the number of conditions in the if function increases and it's directly linked with p. I was wondering if it's possible to increate them into the loop in order to avoid repetitions

Comment: Well, this depends entirely on the conditions that you will create. Would the next extra condition be `Meldungen_num[i,j-(p-3)]==0`? Then yes, you can probably do this very easily.

Comment: Again, you are explaining a step not the ultimate goal. And we need input and expected output to test solutions.

Comment: Also, in your `if(p==3)` it says `i in 1:401`... is this supposed to be `i in 1:length_GP`? And is `j in (1+p):10` the same as `j in (1+p):length(quartale)`? Because then you can save a lot of code.

Comment: Sure, let me provide you an example. I will update the post in a few minutes when the example is ready. Sorry for that I am kind of new here

Comment: I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just for clarification... The problem currently states that in a column, if the first entry is `1` and all subsequent entries up until `p` are `0`, then `p+1` should be `0`. Each `p` should yield its own data frame, so we get `p` data frames.

Edit2: Updated according to clearer wishes.

```
lis <- list()

for (p in 2:9){
  LISTE_neu <- LISTE
  met <- LISTE_neu[1,] == 1 & colSums(Meldungen_num[2:p,]) == 0
  LISTE_neu[p+1,met] <- 0
  lis[[p]] <- LISTE_neu
}
```

Call the results with `lis[[p]]`, so for `p = 2` you use `lis[[2]]`.

**Explanation**: Basically, as `p` increases, you want to look at a bigger part of `Meldungen_num` and see if all values are `0`. Since all values must be `0`, their sum must also be `0`. Therefore, I take all the values of interest (`Meldungen_num[2:p,]`) and sum them (`colSums`). Note that this happens for all columns simultaneously (so we get as many sums as there are columns). I then compare all these to 0, and for each column separately you get the answer. So that one single line checks all the columns for a given `p` all at once. `met` then contains which columns satisfy your conditions.

Then, I write `0` to only those columns that met our conditions using `LISTE_neu[p+1,met] <- 0`. Then, I store this new table in the list `lis` and go to the next `p`.

Comment: Not exactly. Let me precise something.  It tests the condition on the matrix Meldung (also a 10x10 matrix with 1 and 0) and if it satisfies the condition then it replaces in the other matrix. My code works here but I want to implement everything in one single loop. Am i cleary enough?

Comment: @eliorico I updated the answer to fit your code better. If this works, don't forget to press the check mark next to my answer, so that the question is officially answered.